# How to use variables in sed with both single quote and double quote

Tags: linux, sed

I have this command, which creates a copy of a line and changes some substrings:

test file content before:

```
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
```

The working command:

```
sed -i -e '/;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"/ a push "route
172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0"' test
```

test file content after:

```
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0" 
push "route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0"
```

Now if I have a `var=172.31.0.0`, how can I use it in this scenario, when I put it like this:

```
sed -i -e '/;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"/ a push "route $var 255.255.0.0"' test
```

I got this:

```
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0" 
push "route $var 255.255.0.0"
```

I know single quotes make everything inside it literal string, now how can I use a variable here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason that you *must* use sed for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of different options.

Escape the `""` around the string.

```
 \"route 192.68.20.0. 255.255.0\"
```

Example,

```
$ var="172.31.0.0"
$ echo ';push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"' \
  | sed -e "/;push \"route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0\"/ a push \"route $var 255.255.0.0\""

;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0"
```

OR

Put single quotes around `$var` when they are defined inside a string with double quotes.

```
$ echo ';push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"' \
  | sed -e '/;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"/ a push "route '$var' 255.255.0.0"'

;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `sed` command may help you in same.

```
sed "s/;\([^ ]*\) \"\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1 \2 $var \3\4/"   Input_file
```

OR in case you don't want 192 value in output then following may help:

```
sed "s/;\([^ ]*\) \"\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1 \2 $var \4/"  Input_file
```

Where variable `var` has value as mentioned by you. In case you want to do these operations on a specific line which has some specific text then following may help you in same.

```
sed "/push/s/;\([^ ]*\) \"\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1 \2 $var \3\4/"  Input_file
```

OR

```
sed "/push/s/;\([^ ]*\) \"\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1 \2 $var \4/"  Input_file
```

Also if you are happy with above command's result then use `sed -i` command to save output to Input_file itself(which you had used in your post too).

Comment: Would it work in a big file? the line I want to replace is just one of many lines

Comment: @Casper, if that is the case then you could ass like `/search_string` before `s` and then it will look for only that line to do these changes. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @Casper, added that kind of example too in my answer now.

Comment: hey thx, but I can search for exact line with double quotes in it, like `;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"`